# I tried using union clause in GoogleSQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My question is - Top 5 states with highest/lowest average freight value - sort in desc/asc limit 5

```
SELECT c.customer_state, ori.freight_value AS freight
FROM sql_projects.orders o
INNER JOIN sql_projects.customers c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN sql_projects.order_items ori ON o.order_id = ori.order_id
GROUP BY c.customer_state, freight, o.order_purchase_timestamp, o.order_delivered_customer_date, o.order_estimated_delivery_date, o.order_delivered_customer_date
ORDER BY freight ASC
UNION ALL
SELECT c.customer_state, ori.freight_value AS freight
FROM sql_projects.orders o
INNER JOIN sql_projects.customers c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN sql_projects.order_items ori ON o.order_id = ori.order_id
GROUP BY c.customer_state, freight, o.order_purchase_timestamp, o.order_delivered_customer_date, o.order_estimated_delivery_date, o.order_delivered_customer_date
ORDER BY freight DESC
LIMIT 5
```

For some reason Bigquery is giving me an error - Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword UNION at [7:3]

I tried a number of thing , like creating two separate cte and tried joining them using full join , but I didn't like the result

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that error don't use the first order by clause:

```
SELECT c.customer_state, ori.freight_value AS freight
FROM sql_projects.orders o
INNER JOIN sql_projects.customers c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN sql_projects.order_items ori ON o.order_id = ori.order_id
GROUP BY c.customer_state, freight, o.order_purchase_timestamp, o.order_delivered_customer_date, o.order_estimated_delivery_date, o.order_delivered_customer_date
UNION ALL
SELECT c.customer_state, ori.freight_value AS freight
FROM sql_projects.orders o
INNER JOIN sql_projects.customers c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN sql_projects.order_items ori ON o.order_id = ori.order_id
GROUP BY c.customer_state, freight, o.order_purchase_timestamp, o.order_delivered_customer_date, o.order_estimated_delivery_date, o.order_delivered_customer_date
ORDER BY freight DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The `UNION ALL` forms a single resultset via the select statements and THEN that result gets ordered.

However I think there may be a simpler solution, try this:

```
SELECT c.customer_state, sum(ori.freight_value) AS freight
FROM sql_projects.orders o
INNER JOIN sql_projects.customers c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN sql_projects.order_items ori ON o.order_id = ori.order_id
GROUP BY c.customer_state
ORDER BY sum(ori.freight_value) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

---

Note that in my suggested solution that I don't use the column alias "freight" in the order by clause. I do this because alias can be changed, so you also have to remember to change them in the order by clause. Instead, if you just repeat the source (even if this is an aggregation) you don't have that renaming issue and I believe it is easier overall. Also, there is absolutely no performance gain by using a column alias in an order by clause (conversely, there is no performance penalty in using the source reference even if its an aggregation).